# Wordpress 'Undo' CSS of parent theme in child theme

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I made customizations of the Wordpress TwentyFourteen theme. Of course I created a child theme. In my child theme I don't need the horizontal menu. I want the mobile dropdown menu displayed until 1008px. From 1008px onwards, I hide the primary navigation menu and use the sidebar menu instead.

In the parent theme there is a lot of css code in:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 783px) { 

}
```

The css code  between these brackets, takes care that the mobile dropdown menu is replaced with a horizontal dropdown menu (on a screenwidth higher than 783px) .

The easiest way to show the mobile menu instead of the horizontal menu until 1008px, is to remove the "@media screen and (min-width: 783px) section" from the parent theme, but of course this is not the way to do it.

Is there a way to 'undo' the css declration of parent theme "@media screen and (min-width: 783px) section" in the child theme?

Or is there another solution?

Comment: Rewrite it in your child them to overwrite the declarations found in it?

Comment: That is indeed an option, but there a 200 lines of css declarations to rewrite. Already started with it...